# object with svg can only click around it

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, navbar

I cant seem to click an Icon I set up in my html from an svg file. I can only click around it and it will bring me to the right page. Iv'e looked online but nothing worked for me.

Also if you could provide reason since I am new to html and trying to learn.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --colorPrimary: #FF00EF;
  --colorGray: #D5D5D5;
}

#topnav {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 5%;
}

.horizontalList {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.horizontalList li {
  display: inline;
}

.horizontalList a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Platino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Platino, serif;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.horizontalList a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#leftalignment {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#rightalignment {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}

#stretch {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Recipes, Groceries & Delivery | Lesn</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topnav" align="center" class="horizontalList">
    <ul class="dropDownContent">
      <li><a id="leftalignment" href="#home">Nike</a></li>
      <li><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#inspiration">Inspirations</a></li>
      <li><a id="rightalignment" href="#register">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a id="rightalignment" href="#bag"><object width="22px" height="22px" data="svg/shoppingbag.svg"></object></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I cant seem to add the svg file into the snippet.

My svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 489 489" style="enable-background:new 0 0 489 489;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Comment: Please add your code into snippet, So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that

Comment: @Kristofer You can add a snippet if you edit your post. Theres a symbol in the toolbar with `<>`. The rest is selfexplanatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your `shoppingbag.svg`'s code inline into the html, it is completely valid:

```
<body>
    <div id="topnav" align="center" class="horizontalList">
        <ul class="dropDownContent">        
          <li><a id="leftalignment" href="#home">Nike</a></li>
          <li><a href="#shop">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#inspiration">Inspirations</a></li>
          <li><a id="rightalignment" href="#register">Log In</a></li>
          <li>
            <a id="rightalignment" href="#bag">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M16 6v-2c0-2.209-1.791-4-4-4s-4 1.791-4 4v2h-5v18h18v-18h-5zm-7-2c0-1.654 1.346-3 3-3s3 1.346 3 3v2h-6v-2zm10 8h-14v-4h3v1.5c0 .276.224.5.5.5s.5-.224.5-.5v-1.5h6v1.5c0 .276.224.5.5.5s.5-.224.5-.5v-1.5h3v4z"/>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I tried your svg and its working but for my svg it wont show. Ive updated my question for my own svg

Comment: Your svg does not seem to be a valid drawing. It does not contain anything but an empty canvas... I think there should be *something* in it to click on.

Comment: nvm Ive solved it. If I insterted it that way I had to change the width and the height